# How to access the raw widget pixels rendered on the screen?

Tags: c++, qt, qtwidgets

I am trying to extract the pixel data from every frame, but when I try to get the `pixmap` it returns null. I thought that the pixmap would return the actual pixel data of what was on the screen, similar to `glReadPixels` but I think I am mistaken. I think it's meant to access the pixel map of the result of `setPixmap`.

Is there a way to access the raw pixels rendered on the screen? With the below example, "Hello World" is rendered on the screen and I want the actual pixel data of that label.

```
QWidget window;
window.resize(1280, 720);
window.show();
window.setWindowTitle(QApplication::translate("toplevel", "Top-Level Widget"));

QLabel *label = new QLabel(QApplication::translate("label", "Hello World"), &window);
label->move(500, 500);
label->raise();
label->show();
QPixmap pixmapVal = label->pixmap(Qt::ReturnByValue);
```

Comment: Have a look at [QImage::bits()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#bits)

Comment: I have not, been playing around with it. It returns a pointer to an unsigned character, so I am guessing the stride is 3? i.e. positions 0-3 is pixel data for pixel 0, 4-7 is pixel data for pixel 1, etc. Is that correct?

Comment: You can add a pixmap to a QLabel, like an icon on a button. The documentation is not very clear about that, reading the code on [woboq](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qlabel.cpp.html#555) can give you a bit of an idea. The value you get back is indeed what you specify with setPixmap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Cause

[QPixmap](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpixmap.html):

> The QPixmap class is an off-screen image representation that can be used as a paint device

In other words, it is a drawing canvas and, as any other canvas, if you have not drawn on it, it would be empty.

On the other hand `QLabel` serves as a view for the pixmap, not as its content, and when you try to access the pixmap of the `label` without having set one, it returns `null`.

### Solution

There is of course a way to make a widget, the label in your case, content of the pixmap and access the pixel data. My approach to the this problem would be like this:

1. Create an empty `pixmap` with the size of the `widget` whos pixel content you want to access, e.g.:

   ```
    QPixmap pixmap(widget->size());

    pixmap.fill(Qt::transparent);
   ```
2. Use [`QWidget::render`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#render) to render the content of the widget onto the pixmap:

   ```
    widget->render(&pixmap);
   ```
3. Convert the pixmap to `QImage` and use [`QImage::pixel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#pixel-1) or [`QImage::pixelColor`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#pixelColor-1) to access the rgb data of the pixel at `(pixelX, pixelY)` like this:

   ```
    pixmap.toImage().pixelColor(pixelX, pixelY);
   ```

### Example

Here is an example I have prepared for you to demonstrate how the proposed solution could be implemented:

```
#include "MainWindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWidget w;
    auto *label = new QLabel(QObject::tr("Hello World"), &w);

    label->move(500, 500);
    label->raise();

    w.setWindowTitle(QObject::tr("Top-Level Widget"));
    w.resize(1280, 720);
    w.show();

    QPixmap pixmap(label->size());

    pixmap.fill(Qt::transparent);

    label->render(&pixmap);

    int pixelX = 10;
    int pixelY = 5;

    // Access image pixels
    qDebug() << pixmap.toImage().pixelColor(pixelX, pixelY);

    return a.exec();
}
```

### Result

For the pixel at `(10, 5)` the example produces the following result:

> QColor(ARGB 1, 0, 0, 0.156863)

Comment: Yep this works! I originally just looped through the width and height and just called `.pixel(row, col)`. Any idea on how to use `.bits()`. It has a pointer to the first pixel value and I am guessing that each pixel is 32 bits (ARGB assuming each channel is 8 bits), so I would need to for loop through and use sizeof(uchar) * label->size() * 4?

Comment: @joethemow, no. I have never used it.

Comment: @joethemow, there's further info about that at https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qimage.html#scanLine